# how to delete old files in ftp with bash

Tags: backup, bash, ftp

I have a backup ftp server and I have a CRON bash sending all backups here.

Right now I have to manually delete all old files, but I would like to automate this process with a CRON bash

The remote FTP does'nt have date on files (I don't know why), but backups are named by date (%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).

I thought of listing all files in the directory, sorting them by name and deleting all files with index > X but I don't know how to do that

My current code is :

```
ftp -inv $ftphost << EOF
user $ftpuser $ftppass
put $savepath.bz2 mysql/"$dbname"/"$datum".sql.bz2
bye
EOF
```

Comment: Which OS is this? I've never heard of a UNIX-like OS which doesn't have file creation or modified meta data.

Comment: all files are dated in 2021 at the same hour, I don't control this ftp server

Answer (score 2):

This solution certainly isn't waterproof but if your backup job runs daily and you want to keep 1 month worth of backups you could delete the file that is one month old with something like:

```
old=$(date -d 'now -1 month' +'%Y-%m-%d')
```

And then in the FTP section

```
mdelete mysql/"$dbname"/"$old"*.sql.bz2
```

Depending on the FTP server you mau need to toggle `glob` first.  The `mls` command should tell you whether or not the file name expansion works.